Child <div> Element going out of Parent <div> Element
i want the a child element inside a parent element to follow the mouse cursor to only where the parent elements boundaries are, and to stop there and not go outside it


main = document.getElementById("bar_2")
ball = document.getElementById("ball")        

main.addEventListener("pointermove", (event => {
  const rect = main.getBoundingClientRect();

  ball.style.left = (event.clientX - rect.left) + "px"
  ball.style.top = (event.clientY - rect.top) + "px"
  ball.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)"
}))
html::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 0;
}

body{
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: #1c1a1b;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  color: #cccccc;
}

#bar_1{
  height: 7.5vh;
  background-color: #1c1a1b;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#bar_3{
  height: 7.5vh;
  background-color: #1c1a1b;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#bar_2{
  max-height: fit-content;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

#ball{
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
<div id="bar_1">
</div>
<div id="bar_2">                 
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
<div id="bar_3"></div>



so if i keep my mouse cursor at bar_1 the ball will appear at bar_1 but i want it to stop on the edge of bar_2

Maybe give the bars different colours?

The 'ball' element was allowed to move beyond the boundaries of its parent container because there was no restriction on its movement so it could follow the mouse beyond the boundary of 'bar_2'. I changed the ball's position to absolute, and then changed some of the JS so that the mouse movement is tracked and only moves within the 'bar_2' container.
    #ball {
  position: absolute; /* Changed this to absolute */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

    main.addEventListener("pointermove", (event) => {
       const rect = main.getBoundingClientRect();

  // This calculates the mouse's position relative to bar_2.
  let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  // I have implemented this logic to make sure the ball's x and y positions stay within the boundaries of bar_2.
  x = Math.max(0, Math.min(x, rect.width - ball.offsetWidth));
  y = Math.max(0, Math.min(y, rect.height - ball.offsetHeight));

  // Sets the ball's position inside the bar_2 container based on the coordinates of x and y, centering the ball on the mouse.
  ball.style.left = `${x}px`;
  ball.style.top = `${y}px`;
  ball.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
});


Using absolute doesn't seem to work for me, but relative does. Thank you

So that fixed it?
